# How to create variable based on Mef plugin class

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I am new on MEF, i am trying to adding plugin extensibility to my C# application using MEF framewok.

I am downloading plugins from database and loading via byte[] data.

```
this.PluginCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.Load(RawData)));
```

Everything was working like a magic until tried using base class of plugin.

One of my plugins is looking like:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.ComponentModel;

using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.Reflection;

using PluginCommon;

namespace Plugins
{
    [Export("Plugin", typeof(IPlugin))]
    [PluginMetadata("DownloadManager", "1.0")]
    [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]

    public class DownloadManager : INGPlugin
    {
        WebClient Client = new WebClient();
        public string _text = "qwert";

        public AsyncCompletedEventHandler dc { get; set; }
        public DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler pc { get; set; }

        public void Download(string url, string path)
        {
            Client.DownloadProgressChanged += this.pc;
            Client.DownloadFileCompleted += this.dc;
            Client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), path);
        }
    }
}
```

To use this plugin i need to create a variable typed of DownloadManager. Most of my plugins are same as this sample. I need to create instance of plugin with same type of plugin.

I think i am using a wrong approch, can somebody give me some examples?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of MEF is to decouple plugins / services from the host code (and from eachother).

If you need to interact with the plugin type directly, you aren't getting any benefit out of MEF.

You might want to expose a base `IDownloadManager` interface and export that instead, but you still need to decide whether MEF will be at all useful.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. To be hones, i am fully newbie about plugin systems, i dont have to use mef if i can add plugin support to my application. Plugin system is necesary because i am getting authorized parts from database, this way let me update only one plugin or add new functionalities without updating whole application. If i declare an interface for every plugins, this might still let me update plugins but that time i cant add a methods to same plugin or i cant add new plugins.

Comment: @Xhays: If you want to decouple plugin code from app code, you _need_ to have a stable interface.  No matter what you do, you cannot add a method, because existing plugins won't have it.  Welcome to the difficult world of versioning.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. When i try Quick Watch in visual Studio as "((Plugins.DownloadManager)PController.GetPlugin("DownloadManager")))". PController.GetPlugin returns IPlugin of part. It let me inspect all variables and methods in plugin. (plugin dll is not referenced to application). But same command line is not working in my code even i tried to set referance of plugin. Do you know what kind of mechanism using by vs to inspect plugin methods?